# Xelement.Parse without knowing the namespace

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xelement

Given

```
<Message xmlns:cm="somenamespace">
    <Person>
        <cm:Name>John Doe</cm:Name>
    </Person>
</Message>
```

I get an XML fragment file which contains the following (let's call this Fragment.xml).

```
<Person>
    <cm:Name>Jane Doe</cm:Name>
</Person>
```

I have the original Person element in an XElement object and I wish to replace it with the fragment.

```
original.ReplaceWith(XElement.Load("Fragment.xml"));
```

The problem is the XElement.Load fails because it doesn't know the 'cm' namespace which is declared at the root node. Also, XElement doesn't allow me to set the inner XML. I'm aware that this is a somewhat unorthodox way of modifying XML (dare I say abusive), but this is what I have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you won't be able to get away from the fact that the fragment, by itself, isn't valid xml, and can't be directly parsed. Here's one rather dirty way to address this, using string Xml manipulation and a temporary wrapper for the fragment, containing the namespaces used by the fragment.

```
 const string fragmentWrapper = 
                     @"<Message xmlns:cm=""somenamespace"">@TOKEN@</Message>";

 var original = XDocument.Parse(originalXml);
 var fragmentDoc = XDocument.Parse(fragmentWrapper.Replace("@TOKEN@", fragmentXml));
 original.Descendants("Person")
         .First().ReplaceWith(fragmentDoc.Descendants("Person")
                                         .First());
 Debug.WriteLine(original.ToString());
```